# Issue with HTML image not loading

Tags: html, tomcat

I am new to HTML. I am trying to load an image in the background of my webpage. Looks like something is wrong with the path. Can someone suggest me where I am going wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Login & Registration Page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body background="../IMG_2609.jpg">

        <div style="font-family:verdana;padding:20px;border-radius:20px;border:20px solid #0000FF;">
            <h1> Login Screen</h1>
            <form action="Login" method = "post">
                <center><strong> User Email</strong>:<input type = "text" name = "email"><br></center>
                <center><strong>Password</strong>:<input type="password" name="password"><br></center>
                <center><input  type = "submit" value = "Login"></center>
            </form>
            <br>    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Project Structure]

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: You are serving with Tomcat? If so, then your suspicions are correct that it is about the path of the image, not an HTML or CSS issue. Static content is not necessarily served with the same relative paths as the webapp. To help us diagnose your problem, try to find out if you can access your image through the webserver in any way. Once you find out what URL works to do so, then add this full URL of the image (whatever it may be) to your question. Also, add the full URL of the web page that contains the code you posted. Then we can help find out how to connect the image into the background.

Comment: You were right, the path which brings up the image in the browser worked out for me. But the image is in one of my local drive <body style="background: url('E:/Pics/IMG_2609.jpg') center center no-repeat;">

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [background CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background):

```
<body style="background: url(IMG_2609.jpg) center center no-repeat;">
```

*Always remember that `url` is relative to the CSS file, but in your case since it's inline, it would be to your actual HTML file.*

[Here's an example using a Google image:](http://jsbin.com/fabokubu/1/edit)

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login & Registration Page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body style="background: url('http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png') center center no-repeat;">

        <div style="font-family:verdana;padding:20px;border-radius:20px;border:20px solid #0000FF;">
            <h1> Login Screen</h1>
            <form action="Login" method = "post">
                <center><strong> User Email</strong>:<input type = "text" name = "email"><br></center>
                <center><strong>Password</strong>:<input type="password" name="password"><br></center>
                <center><input  type = "submit" value = "Login"></center>
            </form>
            <br>    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: he want in html ... not css solution

Comment: @Anri - That was never stated in the OP's question. They are using inline styles elsewhere. Shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: It doesn't load still after using above syntax. Do I have to modify anything in my HTML elsewhere?

Comment: You could try `style="background: url('/IMG_2609.jpg');"` Where is the image in relation to the html file?

Comment: When I am opening the page in developer mode in Chrome it shows.."Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Yes I see that when I am using url link of the google png it comes up but what's wrong with my file. It doesn't load.

Comment: We need to figure out 2 things. 1) Is your image file actually there? Can you navigate to it via URL? 2) Where is the image file in relation to your HTML file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58385/discussion-between-sandy-and-code-maverick).

Answer (score 0):

The `<body>` `background` attribute is not supported in `HTML5` (as is evident from your `doctype` declaration). Use CSS instead.

CSS syntax: `<body style="background-image:url('IMG_2609.jpg')">`

Comment: No Luck with this. It doesn't show any error(tried seeing in developer mode of chrome) but the image is not visible in the background

Comment: give <body style="width:100%;height:100%;background-image:url('IMG_2609.jpg');">

Comment: Doesn't help. Do you think I need to modify anything apart from this. Probably doctype?

Comment: no i dont think so. doctype is correct for html5. this is the new convention. did you try giving <body style="background:#333"> and check if the color appears

Comment: Yes,the background changes to dark. I guess something is wrong with the path